# Type 'number' is not assignable to type {}

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Completely new to TypeScript.
I've recently done a refactor on a colleague code and implemented Typescript, since then I've been covering the bugs, but I can't seem to solve this one. Any help would be great!

In this component I validate if the user is logged in and if that's the case the data is displayed accordingly to the amount of users. If there're more than 2 users than a carrousel will be displayed. Main component function will be displayed in a card.

I'm getting the following error:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'BirthdayPerson[][]'.ts(2322)

Is it possible to assign the number type to BirthdayPerson, or the answer lies on a logic refactor?

Type BirthdayPerson:

```
export type BirthdayPerson = {
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
  birthday: string;
  picture?: string;
};
```

BirthdayComponent.tsx file:

```
interface IMainProps {
  numberOfUsers: number;
  displayData: BirthdayPerson[][];
}

function MainContent({ numberOfUsers, displayData }: IMainProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        {numberOfUsers > 0 ? (
          <Carousel displayData={displayData} />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h5 className="font-white text-center">Loading...</h5>
          </div>
        )}
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
    </div>
  );
}

function BirthdayWidget() {
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
  const users = useUsers();
  const [slideCount, setSlideCount] = useState(2);

  const displayData: BirthdayPerson[][] = useMemo(    // ERROR LIES HERE
    () => updateBirthdays(users, { slideCount }),
    [users, slideCount]
  );
  const hasMoreThanOneSlide = displayData.length > 1;

  const shouldDisplayAmountSelect =
    hasMoreThanOneSlide || (displayData.length === 1 && displayData[0]?.length > 2);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Card
          text="Birthdays"
          displayDropdown={<Select options={ITEMS_PER_SLIDE_ARRAY} onChange={setSlideCount} />}
          displayArrow={!shouldDisplayAmountSelect}
        >
          <>
            <div style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
              {isAuthenticated ? <SignOutButton /> : <SignInButton />}
            </div>
            <MainContent displayData={displayData} numberOfUsers={users.length} />
          </>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default BirthdayWidget;
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you :)

I've tried to add the "number" type to the BirthdayPerson type, but it just gives me other bugs

Comment: `number`s and `BirthdayPerson`s are completely incompatible, so i don't see what the code is trying to do. Is it correct that `updateBirthdays` returns a number? Can you show us that code?

Comment: Sure, this is updateBirthdays, it returns a number, there are plenty of "any" type in this code
```export const updateBirthdays = (people: BirthdayPerson[], { slideCount }: IUpdateData): number =>
  getBirthdays(people, 30).reduce((resultArray: any[], item: BirthdayPerson, index: number) => {

    const result = [...resultArray];
    const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / slideCount);
    if (!result[chunkIndex]) {
      result[chunkIndex] = []; // start a new chunk
    }

    result[chunkIndex].push(item);
    return result;
  }, []);

export default { updateBirthdays };```

Comment: Please put the code into the question, not the comments; the comments have terrible code formatting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider [edit]ing the code in your question to be a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE which demonstrates your problem without demonstrating unrelated problems.  Ideally you'd remove any code that isn't directly involved with your issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type on your `updateBirthdays` function is incorrect. It does not in fact return a `number`. Typescript can't point this mistake out because of the `any`'s. I believe the correct types are:

```
export const updateBirthdays = (
  people: BirthdayPerson[],
  { slideCount }: IUpdateData
): BirthdayPerson[][] =>
  getBirthdays(people, 30).reduce(
    (resultArray: BirthdayPerson[][], item: BirthdayPerson, index: number) => {
      const result = [...resultArray];
      const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / slideCount);
      if (!result[chunkIndex]) {
        result[chunkIndex] = [];
        // start a new chunk
      }
      result[chunkIndex].push(item);
      return result;
    },
    []
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This refactors drive me crazy, will finish tackling all the "any" to see what comes from there. You were extremely helpful!